# Request recommendation, Can Ubuntu be used for Home Media Server with desktop machine & how?

Tags: server, system-installation, nas

This is my first post / question in this forum and SORRY for the lengthy post.

I am basically looking for Home Media Server for the following tasks to be accomplished:

1. Media Server for my Photo, Video and Audio Files
2. Server for Torrent Downloads
3. Server to connect and sync my OneDriver and Google Driver on personal files
4. Access the Server from outside over internet securely

Presently, I use a Macbook Pro Mid-2010 model which is doing all of this, as follows:

1. Media Share using XMBC - Connected to my External USB HDD WD 2TB
2. Torrent download on same machine
3. Sync of Cloud Storage in the same machine
4. Not done at present as already the machine has become a real workhorse!!

Due to the above fact, I am unable to carry out my regular work as the machine being dead slow. So practicing ON/OFF feature as and when required depending upon the need. Tiring as you may know...

My office is selling old PCs for its employees at cheap price (250 USD) and I was thinking to use this to build my Home Server and separate all the above mentioned activities out of my Macbook. I am on a strict budget. Hence, was wondering to get hold of the slim tower HP Compaq 8200 Elite i5 - 2500 with 500GB HDD, 8 GB RAM and CD/DVD Drive for this purpose and configure it.

I am aware it is not a server grade machine to be used for such purpose, however, with little budget on hand, I cannot think of constructing a NAS kind of machine which I read in the internet.

I am not too techy at the same time not a novice, so request the members to help me on taking the right decision with your expert knowledge and also highlighting the pros and cons associated with the decision.

I would also require support in getting the machine up and running, if your vote is yes to go ahead on this proposal.

I would like a GUI Interface in the proposed machine which I should be able to manage from my Macbook. Can all also this be done with Ubuntu without much deep diving? Is the machine ok for 24X7 operation and ideal state?

Thanks in anticipation of your support / help. Any sorry, if my mail is not structured enough to align to the topics in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the machine seems perfectly fine if you don't want lots of people accessing it at the same time.
Supposing you want to access it from your macbook (is this correct?) locally, then you don't necessarily will need a GUI on your "NAS" , but it will make things easier.
So, step by step:

1:
follow [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ubuntu-Linux) guide to install Ubuntu.
I would not necessarily use Ubuntu because you won't be spending much time in front of the desktop anyway, you could install something more lightweight.

2:
Set up WiFi on your installed linux distro

3:
In OS-X open your file browser and go to "network", there you should find your HP in the list of devices connected to your network.
Select it, log in with your account details and you should be able to access the files on your computer

If you have any more questions or want more details, just leave a comment

Comment: Thanks for your positive feedback. So, do you suggest something more light weight to carry out these tasks other than Ubuntu? What is it? I need the GUI as I need to configure Media Server and Torrents Clients, etc. Yes I will be accessing / administering from my Macbook not just a file sever but also to control the machine as you have also rightly mentioned I don't propose to use a regular monitor / keyboard setup for the proposed machine. Also, now I have to buy a wWiFi card for the machine as I don't suppose it would come with a Wifi MB prebuilt. If Ubuntu then Desktop or Server? Thanks.

Comment: Only, two or max 3 sources will be accessing the machine for Data as follows: 1. Self thru remote or home network, 2. My Smart TV for Content, 3. iPhones or iPads for content.

Comment: your computer should have absolutely no problem handling Ubuntu, but it's just that Ubuntu is more of a Desktop distro. I don't know what you mean when you say your not exactly a novice, but if you want things easier you could use the very user-friendly [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/) (Ubuntu-based) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) , a very lightweight and fast distro (lxde desktop looks pretty bad though) or pick a distro you like the most from [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/).

Comment: But if you are going to sit in front of your computer pretty often, i'd definitely go with Ubuntu.